# What is the JNI flow for native Thread class functions?

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

I am new to the JNI area and my aim is to study the native methods of java.lang.Thread such as registerNatives and start0() so that I get to understand at the OS level what are the OS operations that happen when a Thread is 
a)created
b)started

So I cam across various tutorials for JNI so as to understand just the basics. It looks like there are 4 main steps
a) write the declaration of the native method(s) in a class (like start0() in Thread.java)
b) use javah tool in jdk/bin to generate a .h file
c) include these generated .h files and other common .h files in jdk/include to the c/c++ project env
d) write the required c++ function.

Please correct me if I have missed a step.

Questions- 
1) When I apply the step b)  to a standard java file like Thread.java, I couldn't find something like Thread.h in the JDK and it's source. What should be the exact location of the same ? I got the link of Thread.h in apache harmony http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/enhanced/sandbox/bootjvm/bootJVM/jni/src/harmony/generic/0.0/include/java_lang_Thread.h and this is exactly the same file which I expected to be there in jdk.
2) I see a file called Thread.C at jdk\src\share\native\java, this file includes the file I expected in point number 1, java_lang_Thread.h. Thread.C file contains code

```
Java_java_lang_Thread_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
```

{
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls, methods, ARRAY_LENGTH(methods));
}
Ideally I would have expected this code to be there in Thread.h, why is it there in Thread.C and what is it's significance ?
3)There is a file called thread.cpp at openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime and it contains all the method definitions, now starting from Thread.h

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_java_lang_Thread_start(JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

how can we map it to Thread.start because I couldn't notice a mapping between start0() to start().
4) Since I am a java programmer and may have hard time understanding c++ code in Thread.CPP, could someone guide me to a link which may contain theory of these methods like set_stack_base(NULL) etc ?

Comment: There are a whole lot of XY questions here. What is it you are actually trying to discover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a link to the jdk or the java threading source. Perhaps if you provided one, I could solve your problem.

However, what I gathered from your question is: "How does the Thread.h link to the Thread.cpp?" If that is what you are asking then think of it this way:

Thread.h just contains a bunch of declarations. Similar to that of a Java interface.
Thread.c contains the implementation of that interface.

As for my second guess as to what you're asking: "How does java create a native thread?".

If I had to take a huge guess at Java creating a thread on Windows, I'd say the definition is either written using WINAPI (windows only) or the C++ stl (portable):

Suppose you have a java Threading class:

```
public class Threading {
    static{ System.LoadLibrary("Threading"); }

    private Runnable r = null;
    private native void StartNativeThread(Runnable r);

    public Threading(Runnable r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public void start() {
        StartNativeThread(this.r);
    }
}
```

The above class is passed a runnable in its constructor. When you call start, it calls the native function "StartNativeThread" and that function is going to take the runnable as a parameter.
On the C++ side, it will create a thread and that thread will call Runnable.run which it got from the java side.

WINAPI-C++:

```
//object that will hold all thread information.
struct ThreadParams
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    jobject runnable;
};

//function that the thread will call.
DWORD __stdcall RunnableThreadProc(void* ptr)
{
    ThreadParams* p = reinterpret_cast<ThreadParams*>(ptr); //get our thread info from the parameter.
    JNIEnv* env = p->env; //grab our env.
    jobject runnable = p->runnable; //grab our runnable object.
    delete p; //since we allocated on the heap using new, we must delete from the heap.
    //this is because c++ does not have garbage collection.

    jclass RunnableInterface = env->GetObjectClass(runnable); //get our java runnable interface instance.
    jmethodID Run = env->GetMethodID(RunnableInterface, "run","()V"); //get the run method function pointer.
    env->CallObjectMethod(RunnableInterface, Run); //call RunnableInterface.run();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIExample_StartNativeThread(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject runnable)
{
    ThreadParams* ptr = new ThreadParams(); //create an object to store our parameters.
    ptr->env = env;  //store the env parameter.
    ptr->runnable = runnable; //store the runnable object.

    //create a thread that calls "RunnableThreadProc" and passes it "ptr" as a param.
    CreateThread(0, 0, RunnableThreadProc, reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr), 0, 0); 
}
```

Now the above looks quite complicated to be completely honest but that is what WINAPI is. It is an API written for windows in the C Language.

If you have a C++x11 compiler and wish to avoid winapi and use STL-C++, this can be done in a couple lines.
Assume that we have the same java class as above, then our function becomes:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIExample_StartNativeThread(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject runnable)
{
    std::thread([&]{
        jclass RunnableInterface = env->GetObjectClass(runnable);
        jmethodID Run = env->GetMethodID(RunnableInterface, "run","()V");
        env->CallObjectMethod(RunnableInterface, Run);
    }).detach();
}
```

Note that `[&]{....}` is a Lambda Function. It means a function that can be created inside of another function or parameter.

The above can also be translated / is equivalent to:

```
void ThreadProc(JNIEnv* env, jobject runnable)
{
    jclass RunnableInterface = env->GetObjectClass(runnable);
    jmethodID Run = env->GetMethodID(RunnableInterface, "run","()V");
    env->CallObjectMethod(RunnableInterface, Run);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIExample_StartNativeThread(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject runnable)
{
    std::thread(ThreadProc, env, obj).detach();
}
```

Now implementing other things like stop and pause is just as easy. You simply do that on the java side inside your runnable. OR you can do it on the C++ side using WINAPI's `TerminateThread` and `WaitObject` and the likes. OR if you choose to use STL-C++ then you'd use an `std::condition_variable`.

I hope that clears up some things. If you have any further questions, you can just post a comment or make a new thread. Up to you. Otherwise, if I missed something or interpreted your question wrong, then please clarify it.

---

**EDIT..** So for the actual implementation, we can see that Thread.c includes jvm.h. Thus we must find jvm.h and jvm.cpp.

A quick search comes up with:

Thread.h: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c

JVM.h: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.h

JVM.cpp: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp

If we now search for any of the functions from thread.c.. We can see in thread.c that start0 is mapped to JVM_StartThread, and all other thread functions is mapped to JVM_XXXXSomeThreadFunc...

We must now look for these JVM_ functions within JVM.h and JVM.cpp. Once found, you have the source of how it is all done.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames-Thanks for your answer
The link to Thread.C is [link]http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c
The link to Thread.CPP is [link]http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rbackman/7127792.1/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp.cdiff.html
As I said Thread.h , I could not find the location in the jdk source code and would need assistance.

Comment: I ended the end of my post to reflect the links to the JVM's thread functions.